# What does ** mean in a path?

Tags: node.js, unix, gruntjs, glob, npm-scripts

ive been setting up Grunt for my web app to auto build it and im seeing paths like

```
/path/to/file/**/*.js
```

i understand what one wildcard means, but what does 2 in a row mean?

Comment: [the docs](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/wiki/Configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

`/path/to/file/**/*.js` matches any number of directories between `/path/to/file/` and `/*.js`. As opposed to `/path/to/file/*/*.js`, which matches a *single* directory between `/path/to/file/` and `/*.js`.

Answer (score 11):

this matchers called "glob pattern" they are widely used in shell script and in CLI tools like grunt or npm .they '**' means -- "Matches zero or more directories, but will never match the directories . and .. "
you can read more in the docs
[glob pattern](https://facelessuser.github.io/wcmatch/glob/)