# How to run this code in all subdirectories?

Tags: bash, subdirectory

Found this code (https://github.com/Topslakr/x32Live-CleanUp/blob/master/Delete_Silent) and it works great in Cygwin for what I need, but, I'd like to have it also run in all subdirectories.  Been searching, trying all kinds of things but nothing works.  Not a linux person, btw.

I know it is this first line that needs to change:

```
for wav in *.wav
    do
        V=$($sox "$wav" -n stat 2>&1 | grep "Maximum amplitude" | cut -d ":" -f 2 | sed 's/ //g')
        if [[ $(echo "if ("$V" > "$MAX") 1 else 0" | bc) -eq 0 ]]
            then
                if [ $safe = 0 ]
                    then
                        echo "Deleting Data"
                        rm -rfv "$wav"
                    else
                        echo "Running in Safe Mode"
                        echo "Would delete $wav";
                    fi
            else echo "File $wav not slient"
        fi
    done
```

I do have it working in specific levels of subdirectories by changing the line to:

```
for wav in */*/*.wav
```

But I have varying levels of subdirectories and it would be great if I could run one code instead of several for each respective level of subdirectory.  Anyone know what the solution is?  (Thank you!)

Answer (score 1):

To get the wav files for every sub-directory, you would use:

`for wav in **/*.wav`

*Read more here: [What does ** mean in a path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17205713/what-does-mean-in-a-path)*

Comment: That only runs the first level of subdirectories.  How do I get it to run further down?  E.g. not just y/level1 but also y/level1/level2 and y/level1/level2/level3 etc.

Comment: That does work for any amount of subdirectories. To be sure, just tested this and it does go 5 levels down (that's the max folder depth I have in my project).

Comment: You need to run `shopt -s globstar` first or `**/*.wav` is equivalent to `*/*.wav`.

Comment: Thank you but it's only going to the first level for me.  Found this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28176590/what-does-the-double-asterisk-wildcard-mean.  Says it won't work in Bash until globstar is enabled via "shopt -s globstar", which I tried, but still only going one level.

Comment: Apologies to pjh, didn't see your comment until I posted mine.  ```for wav in **/*.wav
```, checked globstar, it is definitely enabled.  Anyone with any thoughts as to why it is only looking in the first subdirectory?

Comment: @manymanyhaha: Try `mkdir -p /tmp/wav/sub; touch /tmp/wav/sub/foundit.wav; ls /tmp/**/*.wav; shopt -s globstar; ls /tmp/**/*.wav`. Will the last command show the wav file?

Comment: @WalterA did those in series and the first ls showed the wav file.  So obviously globstar is working, just not in the executable.  Thanks for that troubleshooting tip.  So now I need to figure out why it isn't working in the code

Comment: Try figuring it out with small steps like `for wav in **/*.wav; do echo $wav; done`.

Comment: @WalterA That also only did the first level of subdirectories.  So it has to do with the executable